# Adding more than 1 field in v-for is causing an infinite loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to add a payment form for the user to fill out of field.type === 'payment'. However, when I add more than one field to add inside of the v-for loop, I get a “You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.” error. What can I do to avoid this? Here is a snippet of what I'm trying to do

```
<div v-for="(field, key) in page.fields" :key="key">
 <v-row v-if="field.type === 'payment'">
        <v-col cols="12" sm="8">
            <v-text-field //ADDING THIS FIELD BY ITSELF WORKS FINE
                label="Card Number" 
                prepend-inner-icon="credit_card" 
                v-model="card_number"
            />
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="4">
            <v-text-field //WHEN I TRY TO ADD IN THIS FIELD, THE LOOP ERROR OCCURS
                label="CVV" 
                v-model="cvv"
            />
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
</div>

<script>
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('formbuilder', ['form'])
  },
  watch: {
    form(newVal) {
      this.page = newVal;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cvv: '',
      card_number: '',
      page: {}
    }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you get fields? Is it prop, data, or computed?

Comment: @bravemaster computed property

Comment: I think `fields` is causing a problem. Can you show the code for `fields`?

Comment: @bravemaster I added more context above

Comment: @JDub It looks like there are still some relevant bits of code missing. Could you try reducing the code down to a minimal example locally and then posting that here? The error message you mentioned is an infinite *update* loop, which is nothing to do with the `v-for`. It just means that somewhere during rendering you're updating some reactive data, which is causing it to render again.